# ¿Qué significa “túpele con ganas” en la canción El Rey, del cantante mexicano José Alfredo Jiménez?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, méxico, palabras-raras, letras-de-canciones

Al comienzo de la canción [*El Rey*](https://youtube.com/watch?v=EyRN5u59zyM), de José Alfredo Jiménez, después de los gritos y antes de que José cante, el cantor dice:

> ¡Dale José Alfredo, ***túpele con ganas***!

¿Qué significa “túpele con ganas”?

Comment: @walen - Sí es túpele: https://www.albumcancionyletra.com/corregir_el-rey_de_jose-alfredo-jimenez_letra__100389.aspx

Comment: @walen - Tomato, tomahto ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tal y como indica aparente001 en los comentarios, [José Alfredo Jiménez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Alfredo_Jim%C3%A9nez) era un cantante mexicano. Dado que la palabra *tupir* no tiene acepciones demasiado ajustables a lo que quiere poder decir, estuve buscando diccionarios de expresiones mexicanas... y allí surgió algo.

Del Diccionario del español de México, Volumen 2, de Luis Fernando Lara:

> ***tupir*** v tr (Se conjuga como *subir*)
>
> 1. Hacer densa y nutrida alguna cosa, como un tejido. *Las mujeres de hoy en día ya no usan las naguas amarillas ni aunque las *tupan* los olanes*.
>
> 2. *Tupirle* (popular) **Emprender con brío y entusiasmo una empresa o tarea**: *Al trabajo de hoy le tupieron con ganas*, *¡Túpele compadre, que ya es muy tarde!*.

Esta forma parece encajar con el contexto de la canción, por lo que decir:

> ¡Dale José Alfredo, túpele con ganas!

Vendría a ser un:

> ¡Dale José Alfredo, empieza y canta la canción con fuerza!

Donde incluso se podría decir que *con ganas* en *túpele con ganas* es reiterativo, pues *túpele* solo ya traería las ganas implícitas.

Comment: Esto me parece bien.  También encontré 1. *Tupir, v. pop.: Golpear*, de la *Morralla del Caló Mexicano* por Jesús Flores y Escalante; 2. (a) Túpale: métale ganas, hágalo con decisión. (b) "Túpale maestro".Tupirle: hacer algo con ganas. "Tupirle a la chamba" es meterle pata al laburo. "Tupirle duro al pomo" es darle duro al escabio, pegarle duro al trago," de *EXPRESIONES MEXICANAS PARA ARGENTINOS, DICCIONARIO POPULAR*, por Emilio Roberto Petersen.

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco la canción, pero acá está la definición según el [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ave05V8):

> **Tupir**
>
> 1. tr. Apretar mucho algo cerrando sus poros o intersticios. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. prnl. Hartarse de una comida o bebida.
> 3. prnl. Cuba y Ven. obturarse.

Me imagino que la conjugación correcta es `túpele` y no `tupele`.

Imagino también que es una expresión regional, por lo que podría querer implicar algo distinto.

Comment: Nota que en México el imperativo no es tupé sino tupe, y José Alfredo Jiménez era mexicano.

Comment: El imperativo de hecho es `tupa` y `tupe` es la versión formal. "Tupé" suena incorrecto, no sé si alguna parte se use así. @aparente001 A qué viene tu comentario?

Comment: ¿No querías decir lo contrario?  ¿Que *tupa* es formal y *tupe* informal?  Mi comentario lo hice por lo que dijiste, de que el imperativo sería *tupele* (sin acento).

Comment: El imperativo es `tupe`, y en este caso es `túpele` porque es una palabra esdrújula. Yo dije que era incorrecto decir "tupele" (sin tilde) como estaba escrito en la pregunta. Y vuelvo a insistir que `tupa` es informal y `tupe` formal. "Tupa tú", "tupe usted".

Comment: Subir: sube (tú), suba (Ud.).  Tupir: tupe (tú), tupa (Ud.).  Así es en México, no sé de tu país. https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/subir

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, estaba pensando en algo totalmente diferente. Gracias por la corrección!

Comment: ......¡De nada!

Comment: Por favor, chequea la corrección que hice, y haz un rollback si no está bien.